# how to select top 5 category with pivot table python

Tags: python, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

i have a data frame as below :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Salary_Range": ['0-4999', '0-4999', '0-4999', '5000-7999', '5000-7999', '8000-14999', '8000-14999'],
      "Nationality_desc": ['India', 'India', 'Philippines', 'Pakistan', 'America', 'America', 'India'],
      "AgeGroup":['Adult','Adult','Young','Young','Senior','Senior','Adult'],
      "Amount":['10000','24000','45000','21200','43200','12300','54300'],
      "Category" :['Electrical','Electrical','Electrical','House','Toy','Car','House']})
```

i need to group by "Salary_Range","Nationality_desc","AgeGroup","Category" (in the same order) and get the sum of "Amount". Though its straightforward grouping , the challenge here is that i wanted to get this group values only for say Top 5 "Category" ( In my data, though for a particular Salary_Range, we can take only Top 2 , so we can consider Top 2 for my Toy dataset )

I wrote the below code, but i am not able to get only Top 2 "Category" , it gives all available "Category" .

```
frame_mcc=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Salary_Range','Nationality_desc','AgeGroup','Category'],
                        values=['Amount'],aggfunc=[np.sum,len],fill_value=0)
frame_mcc.reset_index()
```

1. The Amount here is for one year. i wanted it to be averaged for a month so the Sum of Amount has to be Divided by 12.
2. Also, how can i visualize this pivot (or) group by ?

Can anyone kindly help ? i m struggling on this for hours now.

Top 5 (or) 2 : "CATEGORY" is by summing the "AMOUNT:

Comment: What's the definition for * Top 5 * on your logic, @Sheriff?
Because on your `df` you have many categories with different amounts, so you mean the top 2 / top 5 in terms of the maximum amount of each category, or the categories with the maximum amount (meaning one category can be in more than one position)?

Comment: @LuanNaufal, Top 5 (or) Top 2 "CATEGORY" based on the sum of "AMOUNT".

Comment: @LuanNaufal, but it should be the Group of all columns mentioned prior to it